# Is it possible to make a module unimportable/hidden at runtime?

Tags: python, mocking, python-import

I have different sets of dependencies that are installed in different environments (i.e. core deps installed everywhere, plus optional deps just for linting, optionals only in production etc).

Locally, I typically have all of them installed, so my code will never accidentally happen to fail importing something. But in production, I just run the code and don't have, for example, Mypy installed. If I happen to need to import something from such an optional dependency (to work around a bug, for example), I might forget to make the import conditional.

Long story short, I want to write tests that forcefully make certain modules unavailable/unimportable/hidden, so that regardless of whether these tests are run, importing those modules will result in an `ImportError`.

**Is there any way to achieve this?** Maybe there's a way to register some kind of hook that allows me to raise my own error whenever a certain module is imported from anywhere?

I've already tested mangling `sys.modules`, but even deleting a module from it will not prevent me to import it, and if I `del` the module itself it only makes it unavailable until I import it again.

Comment: Run the tests inside a container or virtualenv where the extra modules aren't installed.

Comment: I need the solution to be in the code, the tests are run in various environments including other devs' machines and CI pipelines.